# Matplotlib: Legend fontsize not changing when using font with local path

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python3.7, matplotlib to visualize multiple lines on a graph. My end goal is to make only the legend font size smaller, however I'd like to use my font from the same folder my code is in.

The font size specifically for the legend *did* go smaller when I used the font using "mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = font.get_name()" *However* I don't want the code to depend on files in my specific computer's fonts, I want it to be able to work with that specific font regardless of whether or not the code's on my computer, and that's why I'm using a local path.

Everything shows up correctly except for the fact that the size is not altered no matter what I try.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
from cycler import cycler
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import accumulate
import numpy as np


path = 'fonts/GT-America-Extended-Medium.OTF'
font = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
pathofregularfont = "fonts/GT-America-Expanded-Regular.OTF"
fontregular = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=pathofregularfont)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))

cmap = get_cmap(name)   
colors = cmap.colors  
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', colors)))

for index, user in zip(range(int(limit)), counted.keys()):
        print(index, user)
        listofdatesforeveryuser = list(reversed(dictofusersanddates.get(user)))
        counteddates = OrderedDict(Counter(listofdatesforeveryuser))
        cumulativecounts = list(accumulate(list(counteddates.values())))
        dateslist = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in counteddates.keys()]
        print(user, dateslist)



        if int(limit) <= 17:

            plt.legend(prop=font)

        elif int(limit) > 17:

            plt.legend(prop=fontregular)
            mpl.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 6

        plt.step(dateslist, cumulativecounts, linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5, label=(user + '\n' + str(counted.get(user)) + ' likes')) 

ax = plt.axes()
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(fontregular)
    #ax.set_fontproperties(font)
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(fontregular)
name = str(filename).replace('.csv','')
plt.savefig('schedules/Top ' + str(limit) + ' users for ' + name + '.png',dpi=600)
```

I tried (positioned before and after plt.legend and before plt.step and plt.savefig): `plt.legend(fontsize=6)`

I tried (positioned before and after plt.legend and before plt.step and plt.savefig): `mpl.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 6` and `plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 6`

I tried (positioned before plt.legend and before plt.step and plt.savefig): `plt.rc('legend',fontsize='small')`

I tried (positioned after plt.legend and before plt.step and plt.savefig): `plt.legend(fontsize=6)`

I tried (positioned after plt.legend and before plt.step and plt.savefig): `plt.rc('legend',fontsize=6)`

I also tried those options after plt.step and before plt.savefig

The font still remained the same size, and in some instances if I put the fontsize=6 statement after plt.legend(prop=font), it would pick the matplotlib default font with the smaller font, and would ignore the font I specified.

Comment: You will definitely need to set the fontsize ***before*** creating the legend.

Comment: Thank you, will do more tests with that. I tried: plt.legend(fontsize=6) and plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 6 and plt.rc('legend',fontsize=6) and mpl.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 6  -  before creating the legend, but still not working. Will keep trying more.